# Why the output of this line of code looks as it looks?

Tags: python

My friend gave my this code in Python:

```py
a ,= 1------1,
print(a)
```

The output is `2`. But why? Can somebody explain how it works?

Comment: `1 - (-1)` is 2. Same but with more minus signs.

Comment: But how about this commas before `=` and on the very end of the line?

Comment: Teaching you basic language syntax is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
Look up unary minus and subtraction.

Comment: You're setting a tuple containing `a` to a tuple containing 2. That has the same effect as setting `a` to 2.

Answer (score 2):

`a, = 1------1,`
is the same as:
`a = 1------1`

```
1-(-(-(-(-(-1)))))
 |+| |+| |+|

=> 1 + 1 = 1
```

You can think of this comma like this:

```py
a = 1 # a is 1
a, = [1] # a is 1
a = [1] # a is [1]
```

Comment: @khelwood you're right. I've updated the example. Thank you!